# How i can add a refresh button in the views?

Tags: views, ajax, social-network

How i can add a button to refresh new content in views pages or blocks?
like new tweets in twitter's timeline.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Can you show us what (if anything) you tried or considered so far?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/views_nodejs and https://drupal.org/project/ajax_views_refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Views Auto-Refresh](https://drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module..

Project page says

> A module to refresh a view after a specified time interval. Includes
>   advanced options to avoid reloading the whole view, and to avoid
>   causing a full Drupal bootstrap at each refresh.
>
> Suitable for usage on liveblogs, activity streams, comment lists, and
>   any other view where new items are frequently added.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't need any button to refresh the view, every refresh it's cache clear for you unless I'm wrong.

So check if in the twitter's block settings (or view settings) there are any advanced options to say "don't cache" as you can have always fresh contents.

Let me know if it helps.